# MVVM updating Label

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I know this is a frequently asked question, but I'm trying to solve it at least a week now... Read so many Threads, downloaded millions of different MVVM-Pattern-Examples and so on...

I just want to update a stupid label in my MVVM modelview first approach:

```
    void StartUpProcess_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SplashWindow splash = new SplashWindow();
        var ViewModel_Splash = new VM_SplashWindow();
        splash.DataContext = ViewModel_Splash;
        splash.Topmost = true;
        splash.Show();
        ViewModel_Splash.DoWork();
    }
```

The complete ViewModel:

```
public class VM_SplashWindow:VM_Base
    {
        #region Properties
        private string _TextMessage;
        public string TextMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return _TextMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_TextMessage != value)
                {
                    _TextMessage = value;
                    base.OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods     
        public void DoWork()
        {
            this.TextMessage = "Initialize";
            for(int aa = 0; aa < 1000; aa++)
            {
                this.TextMessage = "Load Modul: " + aa.ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
            this.TextMessage = "Done";
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

A small piece from the base:

```
public abstract class VM_Base:INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{       
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
#endregion
}
```

And finally the view:

```
<Label Height="28" Margin="19,0,17,15" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Content="{Binding Path=TextMessage}" Foreground="White" />
```

If I set a initial value for the TextMessage Property in the constructor of my viewmodel, this initial value will be shown after the splash.Show() command.

Setting the TextMessage Property in the DoWork-Method raises the onPropertyChangedEvent but unfortunately it will not update the label in the window. I don't know what I should do... I'm really looking forward for help. Many thanks in advance!

maybe I should mention that the StartUpProcess_DoWork is running in a own STAThread

kind regards, flo

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are performing a lot of work in the GUI thread. And with `Thread.Sleep` you even suspend the GUI thread. Therefore, it will not be able to update the controls.

The solution is to use a different thread for the `DoWork` method. This can be easily achieved with a `BackgroundWorker`. If you provide the GUI dispatcher object to the worker, you can issue GUI changes from there. Although it would be better to use the `ProgressChanged`-Event for that, if it is possible.

Comment: Up to now there is no other work or task. It is planned to use the splashwindow to watch the loading- and software updates-progress. So I'm going to add useful code instead of the thread.sleep functions. Without the Thread.sleep I can't see any message on the screen.